# Namespace usage in object orientated style PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

I have been fiddling around with Namespace in PHP and was trying to make it work, but it fails

Let me show the example code:

test\views\classes\MainController.php

```
<?php
namespace test\views\classes;

class MainController
{
    public function echoData()
    {
        echo 'ECHOD';
    }
}
```

test\views\index.php

```
<?php
require_once '..\autoloader\autoloader.php';

use test\views\classes\MainController;

$cont = new MainController();

$cont->echoData();
```

test\autoloader\autoloader.php

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(null, FALSE);

spl_autoload_extensions('.php');


function classLoader($class)
{
    $fileName = strtolower($class) . '.php';

    $file = 'classes/' . $fileName;

    if(!file_exists($file))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    include $file;
}

spl_autoload_register('classLoader');
```

Throws an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'test\views\classes\MainController' not found in ..\test\views\index.php on line 6
```

Am Im missing something!

EDIT: The code works fine when both the index.php and maincontroller.php are in the same directory without using autoloader but using require_once('maincontroller.php');
Does not work if they are in different directories and with autoloader function. Can anyone sort this out.

Thanks

Comment: Oh sounds like you still can't "get it". please read (1,2,3 part): http://www.sitepoint.com/php-53-namespaces-basics/

Comment: @metal_fan, I have gone through that tutorial and in case if you found the bug in my code, then you can point it out.

Comment: It looks like the error has to do with the autoloader, not your namespaces.  Have you "step through" the autoloader and confirmed test\views\classes\MainController.php is included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems in your code:

The namespace separator (\) is not a valid path separator in Linux/Unix. Your autoloader should do something like this:

```
$classPath = str_replace('\\', '/', strtolower($class)) . '.php';
if (!@include_once($classPath)) {
 throw new Exception('Unable to find class ' .$class);
}
```

Plus, the paths are all relative. You should set your include path. If your site structure is like this:

```
bootstrap.php
lib/
  test/
    views/
      index.php
      classes/
        maincontroller.php
  autoloader/
    autoloader.php
```

Your bootstrap.php should look similar to:

```
$root = dirname(__FILE__);
$paths = array(
    ".",
    $root."/lib",
    get_include_path()
);
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));
include 'lib/test/autoloader/autoloader.php';
```

Now, in your test/views/index.php you can just include the bootstrap:

```
include '../../bootstrap.php';
```

Comment: Thanks Shu, that was awesome support from you, thanks one more time for taking your valuable time to write down the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a die statement to your class loader:

```
$file = 'classes/' . $fileName;

die('File ' . $file . "\n");
```

And you get

```
File classes/test\views\classes\maincontroller.php
```

Is that really where your main controller class lives?